# Maven build and tests very slow on Docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying setup my Gitlab CI/CD to compile and run tests for my Java/Maven/Spring Boot application.
I've setup a Gitlab Runner and created my .gitlab-ci.yml and it all worked, but VERY SLOW.
I've tried many configurations for my runner, without success.

So i made a step back and tried to run the tests on Docker on my local machine.

The build + tests running directly on my machine takes 17min.
The build + tests running on docker takes more than 1h.

The best performance i've got was using using this docker command:

`docker run -it --rm --name comp2 --mount type=bind,source="C:/ProjetosJava/eaud",destination=/usr/src/mymaven -e MAVEN_OPTS='-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xmx4096m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1' -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.3-jdk-8 /bin/bash`

and inside bash i did:

`mvn -s .m2/settings.xml clean compile test`

I need the build inside docker to have at minimun a close time (17min).

Comment: I don't know why your build is slow (and I guess, without further information, no one else will know), but what I do know is that `clean compile test` shows that you do not know the Maven lifecycle. For tests just run `clean test`.

Comment: Also seeing that you configured the memory with 4 GiB memory? Really needed?

Comment: 4gb is a try.. I tried everything, but the build is simple slower than on local machine....

Comment: @renanleandrof sorry, the comment probably sounded a bit arrogant. But nevertheless, you should change `clean compile test` to `clean test`.

Comment: First 17 minutes for a build is a lot. How many LoC? How many tests? How many modules? How long do the tests take? Second: In general a build within a container is always slower than on a bare metal because you are adding several layers...furthermore you have not mapped the local cache in your docker container which means every build downloads a lot..why using Maven 3.3? instead of most recent ones? Why such gigantic memory settings within a Container? Does you Docker daemon support that? Memory enhancement will not decrease build time...

Comment: @khmarbaise 3500 unit tests. Just one module. The tests are like 15 minutes of the total. We use 3.3 because is an old project, doesn't run on latest version. I've mapped the cache, it doesn't download everytime. In fact, this 17min is without downloading. Ive tried many memory configurations, this big memory was a try... =/

Comment: Ok.. first in a single module 3500 unit tests.? Furthermore if those tests are unit tests then  running 15 minutes is tooo long... What does not work with latest version of Maven? Also take into account of JFabianMeier and use only `mvn clean test`... instead of `mvn clean compile test`... because that duplicates parts... CI env use caches configuration ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Found out the problem. It's the maven surefire plugin. Check my answer.

Comment: @JFabianMeier it doesn't make any difference calling "mvn clean compile test" and "mvn clean test" . It's just more accurate way of writing, since test include the compile, but in the end is not wrong, just useless.

Comment: It does make a difference between `mvn clean compile test` and `mvn clean test` you are repeating several steps of the life cycle!

Comment: @khmarbaise you're wrong. By maven is smart enought to doesn't repeat the steps. Doesn't make any difference in the end.

Comment: @renanleandrof Unfortunately you are wrong. It repeats steps...Just try it `mvn clean compile test`... and check the output... things like `default-compile` and `default-resources` will appear two times in your output which means the `compile` phase and the `process-resources` will be repeated two times.

Comment: @khmarbaise "[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date" when maven reaches the Test command. As i said, nothing is done, is the same thing.

Comment: Nothing is done is wrong. The plugin is called which takes time... and the life cycle phases will be repeated...not all plugins handle that correct... so you are wasting time....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the problem, it was the Maven Surefire plugin.

By default, surefire will fork the JVM, and when it do that it doesn't inherit the JAVA_OPTS from the mvn command.

So, i was i able to reduce the time of the build by configuring these configurations to the plugin:

```xml
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:-TieredCompilation</argLine>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

The secret is: argLine with `-Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:-TieredCompilation`
and `forkCount=0`.

Comment: I doubt that the dependency is needed because it's automatically done by the appropriate dependency to your project (junit)... and you really need 1 GiB for unit tests?

Comment: How much time did you save?
Are you back to 17min?

Comment: @UroshT. yes. TIme became equal to the time running through IntelliJ

Comment: Another issue i found after my answer: File writing can be slower on docker also. When you have surefire or coverage writing tests results to files, it can make things even slower.

Comment: @renanleandrof You must use docker on windows or macos, which runs docker by using a virutal machine. You can try to use docker in linux system, such as ubuntu or docker for windows wsl, then you will get similiar IO performance as running outside docker container.

Comment: @renanleandrof I wondering why mvn build and tests is quick in intellj? When you don't add the magic arguments, it forks JVM too.

Comment: @WeiDong that's a good question... If you find out, please, let us know!

Comment: @renanleandrof Hey, I am having the same issue as well. I have some very basic dependencies and it runs so fast in intellij. But when I start building Docker image, it runs super slow. Did you figure it out why is this happening? If yes, can you update a comment to let us know?

Comment: Are you running docker on windows? That's another problem that can add up to my answer here. WSL2 is really slow on reading windows file system. So if your files are in the windows, the docker read/write is gonna be slower than normal.